# Show/Hide mulitple DIVs at the same time

Tags: javascript, onclick, show-hide

I want to allow the user to see the content of an article or view just a list. However when I try this it only hides the first instance:

HTML

```
    <div id="title">Title</div>
    <div id="articlebody">Blah blah blah</div>
    <div id="title">Title 2</div>
    <div id="articlebody">2. Blah blah blah</div>
    <div id="title">Title 3</div>
    <div id="articlebody">3. Blah blah blah</div>
    ... And so on for 10 articles
```

Javascript so chage options

```
    <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('articlebody').style.display='none';">View title list only</a>
    <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('articlebody').style.display='block';">View the whole body</a>
```

As I say that code will hide article body 1, but not the rest.

Comment: Don't use id this way! Only one element can have the same id! What you need is class. Than you can use jQuery to display/hide the elements.

Comment: I have tried Class still happens the same way

Comment: 'id' must be unique, so u better use 'class'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have 2 or more elements with the same ID, that is invalid HTML.

My suggestion would be to change these to classes and use jQuery to hide/show:

```
<div class="title">Title</div>
<div class="articlebody">Blah blah blah</div>
<div class="title">Title 2</div>
<div class="articlebody">2. Blah blah blah</div>
<div class="title">Title 3</div>
<div class="articlebody">3. Blah blah blah</div>

<a href="#" onClick="$('.articlebody').hide(); return false;">View title list only</a>
<a href="#" onClick="$('.articlebody').show(); return false;">View the whole body</a>
```

A neater way would be to create an event listener, meaning you can remove your `onClick` attributes:

```
<div class="title">Title</div>
<div class="articlebody">Blah blah blah</div>
<div class="title">Title 2</div>
<div class="articlebody">2. Blah blah blah</div>
<div class="title">Title 3</div>
<div class="articlebody">3. Blah blah blah</div>

<a href="#" class="viewTitleListOnly">View title list only</a>
<a href="#" class="viewWholeBody">View the whole body</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".viewTitleListOnly").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault(); //Prevents browser adding hash tag to URL
           $(".articlebody").hide();
        });
        $(".viewWholeBody").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault(); //Prevents browser adding hash tag to URL
           $(".articlebody").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your html has some big problems:

first: The `id`-attribute has to be unique in the whole document. For that reason, `getElementById`only returns one value (the first element which is found in the document).

use `class` instead and the according selector

`getElementsByClassName`

second: Use an external function with your onclick.

`<a onClick="yourfunction()">...</a>`

and in the script-block:

```
function yourfunction(){
   var el = document.getElementsByClassName(<yourclassname>);
   for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
         el[i].style.display='none';
   }
}
```

EDIT: for compatibility-reasons you should use `querySelector()` or `querySelectorAll()` [(see Article on MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.querySelector), since it is supported by IE8+ while `getElementsByClassName` is not supported by IE8. Also it's closer to the jQuery Syntax and thus more familiar to the most webdev guys;).

Answer (score 2):

ids don't work for multiple instances, you need to use a class to hide them all or set separate ids and hide them individually

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more one element with the same id in your html! this can be easily accomplished by either putting everything into a wrapper element and hide that one, or use classes and selectors such as those in jQuery `$('.myclass').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably reuse `id`s.

Instead, use `class` names, or get div elements by tag names.

`document.getElementsByClassName("item");`

`document.getElementsByTagName("div");`

Comment: getElementsByClassName isn't supported everywhere

Comment: @user1150525 I thought that too, though it's gained a lot of support over the past few months. Even latest versions of IE support it. But yes, `getElementsByTagName` would be safer if that's a major concern.

Comment: That's a good thing. I didn't used but it because i feared that it isn't well supported.